# How can functional groups be bounded?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, nomenclature, covalent-compounds

When I read about the different kinds of functional groups, they usually have formulas like $\ce{-NH2} $, $\ce{-COOH}$, $\ce {-OH}$, etc.

What does the bar represent? Any bond? Or can it only be a covalent one?

Comment: Yes, the bar represents any bond, which in this case can only be a covalent one.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Why? What about compunds like $\ce {NaOH}$?

Comment: @Qwedfsf because OH is not a "functional" group of "Na".

Comment: We don't apply the concept of functional groups in inorganics, that's why. Otherwise things could have been different.

Comment: @Qwedfsf You will not see anyone write $\ce{Na-OH}$.

Comment: @Hexacoordinate-C Only because $\ce {NaOH}$ is inorganic? Or is there more to it? Is it possible to encounter, say, $\ce {-OH}$ in an organic compound and it not be a hydroxy group?

Comment: I don't understand that last question. What do you want it to be? I mean is the hydroxy group that's in a carboxylic acid a hydroxy group? Does a hydroperoxy group have a hydroxy group?

Comment: I can't think of any -OH group that wouldn't be a hydroxyl group. A chemist would never consider a -COOH group to be a combination of a -C=O (a ketone) and a -OH group. // I'd also stipulate that "functional groups" are abstractions for organic chemistry. Hence the bar in organic chemistry is used for covalent bonds.

Answer (score 4):

Functional groups are a unifying idea in organic chemistry. There are tens of millions of different organic chemicals but many of their key properties are determined by the functional groups they contain. For example, amines (compounds with the $\ce{-NH2}$ group) are basic and often smelly; carboxylic acids (containing the $\ce{-COOH}$ group) are acidic.

The bar in the symbol represents the bond to the rest of the molecule. Sometimes chemists write this slightly differently by including a specific symbol for the rest of the molecule like this: R-OH where R is the rest of the alcohol. So a chemist might talk about a series of similar alcohols by defining R as $\ce{CH3}$ (methanol) $\ce{CH3CH2}$  (ethanol) or $\ce{(CH3)2CH}$ (isopropanol).

This simplifying terminology allows chemists to talk about large groups of related compounds without having to be too verbose and writing out all the details of every structure.

This is an organic chemistry concept so the functional group attaches covalently to a carbon. Some groups can also occur in inorganic compounds but the terminology would be different. For example, Sodium Hydroxide contains an isolated OH but this isn't an alcohol and wouldn't be written or described using terminology related to functional groups.

Comment: So what about *N*-hydroxyphthalimide? Does that contain the hydroxy functional group or not?

Comment: @jan It isn't an alcohol and the functional group would probably be described as something like an "N-hydroxy" or a hydroxyimide. The alcohol functional group is defined by an OH connected to a *carbon*.